# Using git-svn without appending git-svn-id

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Can I use `git-svn` without having the `git-svn-id:` entries appended to my commit message?

I have found the `svn.noMetadata` option comes with a warning (emphasis mine):

> This gets rid of the git-svn-id: lines
>   at the end of every commit.
>
> If you **lose your
>   .git/svn/git-svn/.rev_db file**, git svn
>   will not be able to rebuild it and you
>   won't be able to fetch again, either.
>   This is fine for one-shot imports.
>
> The git svn log command will not work
>   on repositories using this, either.
>   Using this conflicts with the
>   useSvmProps option for (hopefully)
>   obvious reasons.

Is there a danger of data corruption by just relying on the `.rev_db` file or is the warning just placed to signal that there is the danger of losing the mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a danger of data corruption by just relying on the `.rev_db` file or is the warning just placed to signal that there is the danger of losing the mapping?

The latter: everything is hunky dory as long as you have the database.